# Where can I find the source for Ubuntu ARM init?

Tags: ubuntu, init

I have a boot time measurement I want to perform in a very precise manner, and I need to instrument init to do so. What version of init does Ubuntu ARM use, and where can I find its source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for the "init" process, or the Linux bootstrap initialization code.

Either way - they're part of the standard Linux source tree, freely available, and well-documented:

For example:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/
- http://www.kernel.org
- http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/03/27/cross-compiling-the-arm-linux-kernel-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/